# Automatically update a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

Datagrid View in a form gets populated from a List
I have this Form with a datagridview that gets populated from a List.
When i click on the Users button on each row, a list of users also in a datagrid should appear

The datagrid on the new form gets updated by the list i pass, When i click on the Users button this is what happens:

```
 GetUserDescriptorDetails gtUserDetails = new GetUserDescriptorDetails(name, xmlData, CreateListDynamically(name));
 gtUserDetails.ShowDialog();
```

the CreateListDynamically method is like this:

```
 public BindingList<xml.UserDescriptor> CreateListDynamically(string _name)
    {
        foreach (xml.UserDescriptor dbList in xmlData.Users)
        {
            if (dbList.DatabaseDescriptorName == _name)
            {
                users.Add(new xml.UserDescriptor() { DatabaseDescriptorName = dbList.DatabaseDescriptorName, Username = dbList.Username, Password = dbList.Password, IsAdmin = dbList.IsAdmin });
            }

        }
        return users;
    }
```

Now the list is fine, but every time i click on the Users button the rows duplicate, because of the users.Add. How can i solve this?
The fact that i add values is only to populate the list, is there any other way to get the list with the condition:

```
dbList.DatabaseDescriptorName == _name
```

Comment: What is the definition of `xmlData.Users`?

Comment: it's this:   public List<UserDescriptor> Users { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `CreateListDynamically(string _name)` method, you are never clearing the previous `users` list, this will be why you are getting the duplication.
Add a `users.Clear()` before your `foreach` loop and the duplication should go away.

This all ofc assumes that `users` is a class variable since I do not see it being passed into the method as a variable

What you could also do is entirely decouple the `users` variable and just have a temporary variable for your resultset inside your method:

```
public BindingList<UserDescriptor> CreateListDynamically(string _name)
{
  return new BindingList<UserDescriptor>(xmlData.Users.FindAll(x => x.DatabaseDescriptorName == _name));
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i need to add new users in the form and when i clear it doesn't save the value

Comment: is there anyway using the where condition to get the list with that condition?

Comment: See my addition to the answer for decoupling `users` from the method

Comment: thanks but it doesn'T really solve it, hwo can i make this work?

Comment: BindingList<xml.UserDescriptor> dummy = users.Where(x => x.DatabaseDescriptorName == _name).ToList();

Comment: Updated the question with the `FindAll` clause. Keep your head while reading it for it might seem a bit confusing. If you want it a bit more readable, split the creation of the list and the return value in your code.

Comment: Thankyou, one question though, i don't need a new BindingList, because then each time i click on the user button no data will be saved

Comment: Since you want the displayed list to be unique for each click (aka not get duplicated etc), you will need a new list. The new list will get GC's as soon as you are done with using it on the second form

Comment: yes but i don't want a new list, i mean i just want a preselected list

Comment: You can then just remove the `new BindingList<UserDescription>()` part of the code and just return what is inside the parentheses atm

Comment: yes, but then i get this: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<more_ServiceConfig.xml.UserDescriptor>' to 'System.ComponentModel.BindingList<more_ServiceConfig.xml.UserDescriptor>'

Comment: That will happen yeah, you will need to have the `new BindingList<UserDescription>()` in the return type then